# Internet Connection not working - USB LAN connection - from particular modem

Tags: windows-xp, usb, network-adapter, internet-connection

I am trying to fix Internet connection on a friends Dell inspiron 1720 with XP service pack 3.

It has an integrated network card that stopped working, after powering down/up the modem still didnt work I brought it back to my place to try a few things ie check cable, update driver etc... still didnt work.

So I bought a USB LAN connector.  It didnt work straight away but I went to configure the properties and changed the ConnectionType from AutoSense to 100 BaseT 10BaseT Full_Duplex, I basically just tried them all.

From my place when connected to my desktop - 10 BaseT and 10BaseT Full_Duplex worked.
From my place When connected to their laptop - 10 BaseT and 10BaseT Full_Duplex worked.

Happy I went back to my friends house confident it would all work, and it didnt.

Brought it back to mine and it did.

While there, in Network Connections the connection is there recognized, enabled, 'working properly' it just says not connected. Also there is no led on the USB connector

While at mine as above except there is an led on the USB connector and it says connected.

Other difference I can think of is they have a cable modem, I'm plugged into the back of a Belkin wireless router - would this make a difference?

Any other ideas what to try?

(Would getting the model of the cable modem help anyone?)

The USB connector is "DM9601 USB to Fast Ethernet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it doesn't work with your router except in *10baseT* mode is troubling, and suggests you might've gotten a bad unit.

If your router works with other devices in *Autosense* or *100baseT* modes, and you've tried the USB dongle in multiple ports with the same results, consider returning it to the retailer in exchange for another.

On the other hand, if your router is older or you've had other devices that only operate in 10baseT mode with it, this may be a quirk of your equipment.  Your friend's equipment might not have the same quirk, so try switching it back to *Autosense* or *100baseT* for your friend's place.

Comment: At friends place I tried all the settings again from Autosense to 10 to 100 baseT Full duplex etc nothing worked.

They have what looks like an old cable modem (with only one lan output), I've got a relatively new wireless router.

Comment: if you've got a relatively new router and a USB "fast ethernet" device that only connects at 10baseT, and you've tried it with all ports on your router with the same result.... it *could* be a driver problem; you might try updating drivers thru Windows Update or locating a newer driver package from the manufacturer, but once you've exhausted that possibility, "broken device" is about all that's left.

Comment: note "fast ethernet" is a marketing term for 100baseT, so the USB dongle should be capable of that.